# Probabilty of guessing the person based on handness

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a group of n people. Some are left handed and some are right handed. I need to know a random person identity, knowing if he is right or left handed

As conditional probabilty:

Being $P(X)$ the probability of correctly guessing a person identity.

$P(X | left)$ the probability of guessing the person identity knowing is left-handed

$P(left)$ the probability for the person to be left-handed

$ P(X) = P(X| left) P(left) + P(X|right)P(right)$

Then
$ P(X) =  \dfrac{1}{num\_left} \dfrac{num\_left}{num\_total}+ \dfrac{1}{num\_right} \dfrac{num\_right}{num\_total}  $

$ P(X) = \dfrac{2}{num\_total} $

So, you are twice as likely to guess the person if you know weather he's right / left handen, and that doesn't depend on how frequent that characteristic is??

This is mind blowing! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is not clear. Exactly what are you doing here?  Are you separating the right and left handed people and choosing from a smaller group?  Something else?  What is $X$?

Comment: Please define $X$. Why is $\mathbb P(X|\text{left}) = \frac{\text{1}}{num_left}$ and $\mathbb P(X|\text{right}) = \frac{\text{1}}{num_right}$ ?

Comment: Updated, pls check now.

Comment: I'm guessing a person identity among a population, knowing a person feature ( left / right hand) and how frequent that feature is. I wrote here for left  / right but could be gender

Comment: The handedness of the person is not random, so $P(\text{left})$ has no meaning. If you know they are left-handed, then presumably you are selecting someone at random from the $n_{left}$ left-handed people. But this is an altogether different probability than selecting someone at random from all $n$ people.

Comment: What do you mean by "person identity"?

Comment: The person you have to guess is a random person ,so you don't know if its left or right, thereforence assing a probability to that. It's like a experiment with reposition?

Comment: Person identity = guesing which is the person. I'ts like playing the "guess who?" game, with only making a question

Comment: This really makes no sense.  I guess you are picking a person at random from the crowd, not knowing their parity in advance?  But if so, then one of your conditional probabilities is $0$ (if the randomly drawn person has the wrong parity, then you know you failed). If you meant a different mechanism, you need to describe what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following analysis **assumes** that the chance of someone being left handed (for example) is less than $1$ and greater than $0$.

Let's try it with actual numbers.  Suppose that $1$ out of every $n$ people is left handed.

You have a group of $T$ people.  If you try to guess someone's identity, without knowing whether or not they are right handed, your chances are $\displaystyle \frac{1}{T}.$

---

When told whether the person is right handed, $\displaystyle \frac{n-1}{n}$ of the time, the person will be right handed, and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$ of the time the person will be left handed.

$\underline{\text{Case 1: Person is right handed}}$

Probability of this case occuring is $\displaystyle \frac{n-1}{n}$. 
Then, you will be guessing at random from a group of 
$\displaystyle \frac{n-1}{n} \times T$ people.

Your chance of guessing correctly here will be

$$\frac{1}{\frac{n-1}{n} \times T} = \frac{n}{(n-1) \times T}.$$

So, the overall chance of Case 1 occurring and leading to success is :

$$ \frac{n-1}{n} \times \frac{n}{(n-1) \times T} = \frac{1}{T}.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2: Person is left handed}}$

Probability of this case occurring is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$. 
Then, you will be guessing at random from a group of 
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} \times T$ people.

Your chance of guessing correctly here will be

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n} \times T} = \frac{n}{T}.$$

So, the overall chance of Case 2 occurring and leading to success is :

$$ \frac{1}{n} \times \frac{n}{T} = \frac{1}{T}.$$

---

Therefore, your overall chance of success has in fact doubled from
$$\frac{1}{T} ~\text{to} ~\left[\frac{1}{T} + \frac{1}{T}\right] = \frac{2}{T}.$$

Therefore, the new information doubles your chances, regardless of how often someone is right handed.

Comment: amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. Note that $P(X)$ is a weird notation, you’d expect $X$ to be a random person and you’d want $P(X=x)$ for $x$ some specific person. Then note that $P(X=x|\text{$X$ is lefthanded}) = \frac{1}{\text{number of lefthanded people}}$ if and only if $x$ is lefthanded. Else the probability is $0$. (We’ll write $L,R$ for the set of lefthanded and righthanded persons.)

So in
$$P(X=x) = P(X=x|X\in L)P(L) + P(X=x|X\in R)P(R)$$
one of the two summands is $0$ (depending on whether $x\in L$ or $x\in R$). So the total probability is again
$$ \frac{1}{\text{total number}}$$

EDIT: And if you know that $x\in L$ then you are not looking for $P(X=x)$, but for $P(X=x|X\in L)$ (assuming you’ve no additional information and thus just pick a random identity), which is then $\frac{1}{|L|}$. I think you’re mainly having a problem with using unconventional notation and then applying conventional methods to this. You cannot do Bayesian statistics if the notation $P(X)$ depends on whether you know $x\in L$ or not.

Comment: Sorry, I sholud have explained myself better. There's no prior knowledge of whether the person is left or right, you know once the experiment has started. That's why you have to ponder both cases, left handed or right handed. I think second answer is good, but thanks for your time again!

Comment: @Elpocholapantera You do not need prior knowledge for this, you just need to deterministically know that information before you make your decision.